# Cache is null on subsequent sign-in to ASP.NET MVC using MSAL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to cache Access Token using MSAL by following the tutorial provided here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect

I am using ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.7.2.

But I am getting error when calling an Microsoft Graph API by getting the token from cache.

I'm getting the error when my code hits this line:

```
 result = app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

Following the steps when I get the issue.

1. Run the code from Visual Studio.
2. Code hit OnAuthorizationCodeReceived()
3. Able to get the data from Microsoft.Graph
4. Sign-in is successfully.
5. Close the browser.
6. Sign back in.
7. Code doesn't hit `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived()`.
8. Call the Microsoft.Graph
9. Error, `IAccount` is null (no token  found in cache). I expected to get the token from cache
10. Sign-in again.
11. Code hit the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived()`.

The code I am using:

`Startup.cs`:

```
 private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
    {
        IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
        AuthenticationResult result = await clientApp.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(new[] { "User.Read" }, context.Code)
          .ExecuteAsync();
}
```

Class to store token in cache

```
public static class MsalAppBuilder
{
        public static string GetAccountId(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
        {
            string oid = claimsPrincipal.GetObjectId();
            string tid = claimsPrincipal.GetTenantId();
            return $"{oid}.{tid}";
        }

        private static IConfidentialClientApplication clientapp;

        public static IConfidentialClientApplication BuildConfidentialClientApplication()
        {
            if (clientapp == null)
            {
                clientapp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Globals.clientId)
                      .WithClientSecret(Globals.clientSecret)
                      .WithRedirectUri(Globals.redirectUri)
                      .WithAuthority(new Uri(Globals.authority))
                      .Build();                

            // In-memory distributed token cache

              clientapp.AddDistributedTokenCache(services =>
                {
                    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
                    services.Configure<MsalDistributedTokenCacheAdapterOptions>(o =>
                    {
                        o.Encrypt = true;
                    });
                });
        }

        return clientapp;
    }
}

public static string GetData()
{
        IConfidentialClientApplication app = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        var account = app.GetAccountAsync(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.GetAccountId()).Result;
        string[] scopes = { "User.Read" };

        try
        {
            // try to get an already cached token
            result = app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync().Result;// ConfigureAwait(false);
            
           //some functionality here
        
        }           
        catch (Exception ex)//MsalUiRequiredException
        {
            return "error";
        }
 }
```

Comment: Marc_s,  what should I do when the question is edit?

Comment: Have you tried the cache as used in the tutorial? : MSALPerUserMemoryTokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALPerUserMemoryTokenCache(clientapp.UserTokenCache, currentUser ?? ClaimsPrincipal.Current);

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the token cache because there may have been a cache not Encrypt before
Or you adjust this code

```
services.Configure<MsalDistributedTokenCacheAdapterOptions>(o =>
                {
                    o.Encrypt = false;
                });
```